# What how much damage does an unarmed melee attack deal?

Tags: damage, unarmed-combat, melee-combat, shadowrun-6th-world

We played the Shadowrun 6th world beginner set earlier this week and could not find the relevant damage anywhere in the included rulebook or tool cards. We do not have access yet to the full rules, so were wondering how much damage an unarmed melee attack deals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Should be ceil(Str/2) S

I could not find a direct statement about unarmed damage anywhere in the book. The only thing I could scrounge up is this. In the section on grappling, on page 111 we can read:

> If the attack is successful, the attacker does their unarmed combat
>   damage (Strength/2, rounded up) plus net hits.

It is obviously Stun damage, but apart from stating that certain augmentations and powers change it *to* Physical, there is no mention of this either.